# Subtracting two char pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have an input buffer which will in the form

```
-----------------------------41184676334

Some Content
More Content



-----------------------------41184676334

More ContenT!!
```

A variable, will store the boundary marker -----------------------------41184676334

I wanted to know the length between the two boundary markers

Here is what I did

```
char *temp, *temp1;

temp = strstr(input,boundarymarker);
temp1 = strstr(temp+ strlen(boundarymarker),boundarymarker);

int length = temp1-temp;
```

length returns a negative value. Is it not possible to just subtract? If not what is the correct solution? and what is the value it is returning?

Comment: Do the pointers have the same size as the int? (Check sizeof.) Also, is the `bounarymarker` a typo here, or is that also in your original source?

Comment: @MrLister It was a typo. I didnt get you

Comment: @user I compiled your code (well, with declarations of "input" and "boundarymarker") and I get 64 as the value of `length`.

Comment: Did you forget to include `string.h`?

Comment: For storing the differnce of two pointers you's better use a type which is defined to be large enough to hold any value returned by this operation, that is `intptr_t` from `stdint.h`.

Comment: @MrLister: Ohyes, thanks for correcting ...

Answer (score 5):

Most likely boundarymarker was not found in one of the two `strstr` calls.  Can you check for `NULL` for temp and temp1?

Comment: Boundary marker was found. Both temp and temp1 have valid values

Comment: @user1692342 Could you print out the values of temp and temp1 in hex?  Might shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compiler/flags `int` may or may not be a large enough storage container to hold a pointer difference.

If you are working with numeric pointer values then use the `intptr_t` type. By definition it's guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer value.

```
#include <stdint.h>

intptr_t length = (intptr_t)temp1 - (intptr_t)temp;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `strpos` to find the first occurrence of your marker then use it to find the second occurrence and subtract those results.

```
int pos1 = strpos( temp, marker);
int pos2 = strpos( temp + pos1 + strlen(marker), marker );
printf( " %d ", pos2 - pos1);
```

Comment: `strpos`? That's not in the standard library. Why use non-standard stuff if the standard `strstr` is made for it?

Comment: Well, true, but it might make things a bit clearer than using pointer arithmetic to derive the length.. (so, just for clarity and, perhaps, to offer the OP an alternative that they might test and then revert to using `strstr`).